# What are the differences between IBM BlueMix and IBM Data Science Experience?

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, time-series, tensorflow, data

This may seem like a silly question, but as I am going through the documentation for both services it is difficult to disentangle what each does, specifically. From what I've gathered

- BlueMix is essentially an all-in-one cloud platform for accessing various IBM Analytics APIs and you can code in various languages, while
- Data Science Experience is sort of an RStudio on steroids (it even allows you to use RStudio), where I can process massive data sets using IBM's resources instead of my own, but I can also code things in Python if I want.

For my needs, I will be using several different types of data, including time-series physiological data and natural language text (sounds like I'll likely need Watson). I would like to be able to use TensorFlow for my work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable with advanced coding and familiar with modeling technics in R and Python, I would recommend to use the datascience experience, since you will do all the coding.
But if you want to have ready-to-use models and API's, and wont be bothered to tweak or modify some advanced parameters, Bluemix is a good choice for you :)